# CSS select the fourth child in a list

Tags: html, wordpress, css

Is there any possible way to give the forth child a color or another style using `">"` like this:

```
.thisclass > ul > li > ul > li { color: blue; }
```

I'm using WordPress and to not create more CSS classes, I want to give it a style from outside "PARENT".

Here is [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/kdgghchv/)

Comment: take a look at `nth-child` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class, you can do exactly this:

```
.thisclass > ul:nth-child(4) {
    color: blue
}
```

If you need older than IE9 support, then you can cleverly use sibling selectors, like so:

```
.thisclass > ul > li:first-child + li + li + li
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below css

```
.thisclass ul:nth-child(3) {
    color: blue
}
```